# Find the value in where in json clause

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel, vue.js

I have `coupons` table where I have `rules` column which is json

```
rules:"{\"books\":[1,2,3,4,5]}"
```

and I have `book` table which has no relation with coupons table

I also `CartVue.vue` file where I have store the books in cart . 
Now I want to have a attribute called `getCouponArrtibute()` which will return the coupon 
where `$coupon->rules->books` has the particular book id from cart .

So far I have done this

```
public function getCouponAttribute()
{
    $discount = Coupon::whereJsonContains('rules->books', $this->id)->get();
    return $discount;
}
```

and From `Cartvue.vue` I can now access coupon property but it is returning null or empty array every time wheather that book id is in `coupon->rules->books` or not

Comment: What does dd($discount->rules); returns?

Comment: @mrhn It returns this "{"type":"percentage","discountPercent":"10","apply":1,"books":[1,2,3,4,5],"categories":null,"selectedRequirement":1,"requirementValue":null,"selectedLimit":null,"usageLimitValue":null,"selectedEligibility":1} "

Answer (score 1):

Right now Eloquent believes that `$discount->rules` is a `string`. You need to cast this to an object, this is done by utilizing Eloquent Model `$casts` [property](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting). This is done by adding casts property on your `Courpon.php` `model`.

```
class Coupon {
    protected $casts = [
        'rules' => 'object',
    ];
}
```

This should make the access `$coupon->rules->books` work.

Comment: then it will become an array and you cant do object access and you should do $coupon['rules']['books']